# Price not showing correct value/decimals

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I have a problem on my order.blade.php when you type in the minimum amount to order the value is showing zero. As you can see in the image below the minimum amount to order is 100 and the rate for 1000 is 0.00026, the value i should be getting when entering the amount 100 is 0,000026

Please see the image and source code.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU8lM.png)

Source codes

This is div class for where the value is outputed

```
 <div class="form-group price">
 <label>@lang('Price')</label>
<input type="number" id="price" name="price" class="form-control"
disabled>
</div>
```

Here are the functions
I guess this is where i need to do some changes, i have tried using my noob skills but no success doing so.

```
 function getServiceDetails(ser_id) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    data: {ser_id: ser_id},
                    url: "{{ route('user.service_id') }}",
                    success: function (data) {

                        var price = (data.user_rate) ? data.user_rate : data.price;

                        $('.service_name').val(data.service_title);
                        $('.minimum_amount').val(data.min_amount);
                        $('.maximum_amount').val(data.max_amount);
                        $('.price_per').val(price);
                        $('.description').val(data.description);

                        if (data.drip_feed == 0) {
                            $('.drip_feed').css("display", "none");
                        } else {
                            $('.drip_feed').css("display", "block");
                        }
                        updatePrice();
                    }
                });
            }

            var total = 1;
            $(document).on('change keyup', '#quantity, #runs', function () {
                var quan = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
                var run = parseFloat($('#runs').val());
                var total = quan * run;
                $('.total_quantity').val(total);

            });

            $(document).on('change click', '#status', function () {
                var re = $('#status').is(":checked");
                if (re == true) {
                    $('.drip_feed_check').css("display", "none");
                } else {
                    $('.drip_feed_check').css("display", "block");
                }
            });

            $(document).on('change keyup', '#quantity', function () {
                updatePrice()
            });

            function updatePrice() {
                var quan = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
                var pri = parseFloat($('.price_per').val());
                var total = ((quan / 1000) * pri).toFixed('{{ $basic->fraction_number }}');
                $('#price').val(total);
            }
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

Comment: i would console log here and there to understand the flow, to see if anything need adjustment..it s something you should do

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

I think to fix this case check toFixed on updatePrice function
Here is the code that I tested:

```
@section('content')
<div class="form-group">
    <label>@lang('quantity')</label>
    <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>@lang('price_per')</label>
    <input type="number" value="0.00026"  name="price_per" class="form-control price_per">
</div>
<div class="form-group price">
    <label>@lang('Price')</label>
    <input type="number" id="price" name="price" class="form-control" disabled>
</div>
@endsection
@php
$fraction_number = 6;
@endphp
@push('scripts')
<script>
    $('#quantity').keyup(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        updatePrice();
    });
    function updatePrice() {
        var quan = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
        console.log(quan);
        var pri = parseFloat($('.price_per').val());
        console.log(pri);
        var total = ((quan / 1000) * pri).toFixed('{{ $fraction_number  }}');
        $('#price').val(total);
    }
</script>
@endpush
```